# What is the proper use of boost::fusion::push_back?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-fusion

```
// ... snipped includes for iostream and fusion ...
namespace fusion = boost::fusion;

class Base
{
protected: int x;
public: Base() : x(0) {}
    void chug() { 
        x++;
        cout << "I'm a base.. x is now " << x << endl;
    }
};

class Alpha : public Base
{
public:
    void chug() { 
        x += 2;
        cout << "Hi, I'm an alpha, x is now " << x << endl;
    }
};

class Bravo : public Base
{
public:
    void chug() { 
        x += 3;
        cout << "Hello, I'm a bravo; x is now " << x << endl; 
    }
};

struct chug {
    template<typename T>
    void operator()(T& t) const
    {
        t->chug();
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef fusion::vector<Base*, Alpha*, Bravo*, Base*> Stuff;
    Stuff stuff(new Base, new Alpha, new Bravo, new Base);

    fusion::for_each(stuff, chug());     // Mutates each element in stuff as expected

    /* Output:
       I'm a base.. x is now 1
       Hi, I'm an alpha, x is now 2
       Hello, I'm a bravo; x is now 3
       I'm a base.. x is now 1
    */

    cout << endl;

    // If I don't put 'const' in front of Stuff...
    typedef fusion::result_of::push_back<const Stuff, Alpha*>::type NewStuff;

    // ... then this complains because it wants stuff to be const:
    NewStuff newStuff = fusion::push_back(stuff, new Alpha);

    // ... But since stuff is now const, I can no longer mutate its elements :(
    fusion::for_each(newStuff, chug());

    return 0;
};
```

How do I get for_each(newStuff, chug()) to work?

(Note: I'm only assuming from the [overly brief documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/transformation/functions/push_back.html) on boost::fusion that I am supposed to create a new vector every time I call push_back.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (Note: I'm only assuming from the overly brief documentation on boost::fusion that I am supposed to create a new vector every time I call push_back.)

You're not creating a new vector. `push_back` returns a lazily evaluated [view](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/view.html) on the extended sequence. If you want to create a new vector, then e.g. `typedef` `NewStuff` as

```
typedef fusion::vector<Base*, Alpha*, Bravo*, Base*, Alpha*> NewStuff;
```

Your program works then.

Btw, fusion is a very functional design. I think it would be more fusion-like if you'd store actual objects rather than pointers and used `transform`. The `chug` logic would then be moved out of the classes into the `struct chug` which had appropriate `operator()`'s for each type. No new vectors would have to be created then, you could work with lazily evaluated views.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  How would switching to actual objects be beneficial, especially if they're non-copyable? (Not sure if fusion copies).

Comment: Well at the very least, it simplifies memory management (no need to delete explicitly somewhere, exception safe) and you don't have to worry about possible NULL pointers (unless some values are meant to be optional).